# Adding folder list to Dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

When I call the following method as a datasource of a dropdownlist, I get **System.Data.DataRowView** instead of folder names. Where am I doing wrong?

```
public DataTable listFolders()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("fullname", typeof(string));

    string defaultPath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultPath"].ToString());

    foreach (var dir in new DirectoryInfo(defaultPath).GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["name"] = dir.Name;
        dr["fullname"] = dir.FullName;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    return dt; 
}
```

My method call

```
ddl.DataSource = listFolders();
ddl.DataBind();
```

Comment: @TimSchmetler I forgot to translate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ddl.DataSource = listFolders();
ddl.DataTextField  = "name";     // or fullname
ddl.DataValueField = "fullname"; // or name
ddl.DataBind();
```

Otherwise .NET doesn't know which field you want to show and which you want to use as key. You can also use only one of both, then the text is also the value and vice-versa. But you cannot omit it, otherwise `object.ToString()` is used which is the full-typename in case of a `DataRowView`.